# Differential Forms

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question

I just had a general question about differential forms.

**Background**. Let $f = f_k$ and define $f^{k-1}$ on $I^{k-1}$ by $$f_{k-1}(x_1, \dots, x_{k-1})= \int_{a_k}^{b_k} f_{k}(x_1, \dots, x_{k-1}, x_k) \ dx_{k}$$

Note that $f$ is real continuous on $I^{k}$.

> **Question.** What is the intuitive meaning of this? Rudin says that after $k$ steps we arrive at a number $f_0$ which is the integral of $f$ over $I_k$. Is this similar to the notion of the [exterior derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative)? Basically if I want to integrate something in $\mathbb{R}^{100}$ I just have to work backwards?

**Source.** *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Rudin

Comment: just seems like integration, fubini style

Comment: How do you integrate a function of two variables? For example, if you wish to integrate $\int_{0}^{1} \int _{0}^{1} x^2ydxdy$, you would first integrate with respect to $x$ (with $y$ fixed) and then integrate with respect to $y$. In fact, the order in which you integrate in this case (and in a broad class of cases) is immaterial (Fubini's theorem). I believe Rudin proves this in the context you have quoted very elegantly using the Stone-Weierstrass theorem. The idea is that the algebra of all functions for which (a priori) we know Fubini's theorem is true satisfies the hypothesis of ...

Comment: ... the Stone-Weierstrass theorem. More specifically, let ${\cal A}$ be the algebra of functions on $I^{k}$ generated by all functions on $I^{k}$ of the form $h(x_1,\dots,x_k)=\prod_{i=1}^{k} h_i(x_i)$ where the $h_i$ are continuous complex-valued functions on $I$. The uniform closure of ${\cal A}$ is the algebra of all continuous complex-valued functions on $I^k$ by the Stone-Weierstrass theorem. (If you are unfamiliar with the Stone-Weierstrass theorem, then I suggest you look at chapter 7 of Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* where he discusses this result in some detail.)